# How should I prune my pomegranate trees?

Tags: fruit-trees, pruning, tree-care, pomegranate

I have a pomegranate tree that is 6 years old. It didn't get enough water for several years, and was growing under a canopy of other trees, so it only grew about 1 meter (~4 feet) high. How and when should I prune it to stimulate growth?

Answer (score 8):

Depending where you Are from you can prune in early spring before any new leaves or flowers come out.  If you are in a very warm climate you can also prune after all of the fruit is taken in late fall.  Prune or cut at an angle to avoid damaging the tree and prune any dead branches.